# string being appended to image source in Chrome which prevents it from loading

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, umbraco

My code looks something like

```
 var publishedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(node.GetProperty("publishedDate").Value);
 string image = Umbraco.Content(node.Id).GetPropertyValue("postImage").src;
 string categories = @node.GetProperty("categories").Value.Replace(",", ", ");

 <div class="column">
   <img class="post-image" src="@image">
   <div class="post-details" data-equalizer-watch>
     <h5 class="post-category">@categories</h5>
     <h2 class="post-title"><a href="@node.Url">@node.Name</a></h2>
     <h6 class="post-date">@string.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", publishedDate)</h6>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and when I view the image source in Chrome using developer tools, the image src will end up looking like

```
src="/media/8354/collegis_blogs_design_jr_7-23_15_news.jpg?1499808181609"
```

the appended string after the jpg is causing the image to error out. This does not occur in Internet Explorer since no string gets appended. Anyone have any idea why this could be occuring?

thanks,

Comment: Why in the world are you starting with an `<h5>` and then going to an `<h2>` and then an `<h6>`?  Do not use headings for formatting. they are meant to denote sections of a document. Their order should be sequential (per each level), starting from `h1`.

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Umbraco you are using I would get the media path like this:

for v7.6 and above

```
string imageUrl = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("headerImage").Url;
```

for v7.5x and below

```
UmbracoHelper uHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
string mediaUrl = "";
if (CurrentPage.HasValue(propertyName))
{
    var mediaItem = uHelper.Media(CurrentPage.propertyName.ToString());
    mediaUrl = mediaItem.umbracoFile;
}
return mediaUrl;
```

See my blog post about it and for how to do it from a controller.
http://www.codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-a-media-item-in-umbraco/